# Nissan keeps losing Bluetooth connectivity to my phone

Tags: nissan, altima, bluetooth

I have a 2013 Nissan Altima SV. The car offers Bluetooth connectivity, and that feature worked great for about a year; for phonecalls, podcasts, and music.

However, for some time now, when I start my car and navigate to AUX to listen to my phone, it occasionally says, "No devices connected". When I navigate through the menus to look at Bluetooth devices, the car still has my phone listed in its devices, it's just unable to connect.

When this happens, I have to delete my phone from the list of devices, and re-add it. Then, it will work fine for another week or two, before the same problem occurs.

Is this a known issue with Nissans? Is there a software or firmware update that I should look for?

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem on my Nissan Qashqai (Nissan Connect 1). However, I've come to the conclusion that this is a problem on the phone side, not on the side of Nissan Connect, or maybe the result of some incompatibility between the two.

Observations on my side:

- My Android phone (bq Aquaris X5) loses the pairing at irregular intervals. I don't have to remove it from Nissan Connect, I just have to connect to it manually and on my Android phone the pairing dialog pops up. I enter the pin and it works again for a while.
- My significant other uses a Windows Phone and she has absolutely no problems. We paired it once and never had to do this again. Even navigation announcements on her phone work perfectly with Nissan Connect (radio is muted for the duration of the announcement from the phone), which doesn't work at all with my phone.

I have no experience with iPhones, so I don't know if the problem is exclusive to Android.

There is a [lengthy thread in a german Nissan Qashqai discussion board](http://www.qashqaiforum.de/f19/nissan-connect-und-handy-4430/) (more than 500 posts, in german of course, sorry for that) about the problem. In this thread a lot of phone models are reported as working without problems, others are having the same problem.

I'm not aware of any updates for Nissan Connect that would fix the issue. Some people "fixed" it by replacing the infotainment unit with an aftermarket device.

Every time I get an update for my phone that lists something like "fixed bluetooth issues" or something like that I hope that it gets better, but no luck yet. I guess the next time I look for a new phone I'll look which brands are known to be working and factor that in my decision.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to my remote starter.  I haven't pinpointed it just yet, but I seem to lose the device whenever my car is remote-started and runs for a certain amount of time.

Or, it just happens whenever the temperature drops too low; it's been happening almost daily lately.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely related to remote-start.

Comment: My Qashqai didn't have remote start, the problem still happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I used to have the same issue 
What I do is to use another phone to connect up to the car’s Bluetooth.  Then off the engine and start up again.
Use my own mobile phone to connect to Bluetooth.
It should auto connect the next time round :)

Maybe u guys can give it a try too

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue as it seems many different Nissan owners have. I'm pretty sure I found the fix, at least for android users.

These are the steps in order to fix the issue for me.
Go to settings/apps/makes sure to show system apps/find Bluetooth app/ click on storage/ then clear the cache.

I did this over a week ago and haven't lost connection yet. My phone links and everything is fully function every time I get in and start my truck and go. Hasn't dropped the connection even once since doing this.

2018 Frontier SV